# Slider Revolution - Wordpress Plugin | Hover effect on the picture

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying, to make some simple hover effect on slider revolution. How can make this black effect while cursor hovers on the picture and this black "Learn More " block appears in the design?

[hover design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLQvI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Layer Actions" to achieve this https://www.sliderrevolution.com/documentation/layer-actions/ . Refer to "**Show/Hide Layers**" section.